# How do I debug/profile for performance when using Entity Framework 4.1

Tags: c#, performance, entity-framework, linq-to-entities

I just got a request to speed up a single request in an application. I traced the bottleneck back to the Data Access Layer where I am using Entity Framework.

I am new to EF, it seems to have worked ok so far.

My question is: what tools/process should I use to debug this performance problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Additionally to database profilers you can check [very good article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/gg490349.aspx) about the most popular tools available to tune entity framework.

Answer (score 1):

Personally I use SQL Profiler to profile the LINQ to Entity Query generated for SQL Server.  Then I determine the issue in SQL.  AND from this I can understand if I need indices, or need to rewrite the LINQ to Entity Query.

Answer (score 1):

If you're not using the Entity Framework Profiler, you're really missing out. The cost is negligible for the insight it provides.

http://efprof.com/